# High base number systems for compression?

Tags: python, sql, database, encoding, compression

I have a network bottleneck in my system so I want to shave off the bytes.

My current data format is 2 ID bytes, 8 DateTime bytes and 2 Variable A bytes and 2 Variable B bytes.

I suspect the range of A is A: 0 ≤ A < 100 and B: 0 ≤ B < 100

How to I shave off the ID, A, and B data bits. All have a low range of possible values so some system that has base a couple of thousand. I imagine using a character system and then mapping each character to a unique value and then not even needing to do arithmetic. Then use the excessive processing power on decoding each input to a normal encoding (utf-8, base 10... all that)

My question then becomes how to find a good number-character data format / encoding so i can ease that network and storage bottleneck. I dont know if postgreSQL or mySQL has a good answer but ill likely use one of those databases paired with a Django backend.

Comment: I think you are going to the wrong direction.Network bottleneck usually do no depend on such small compression. Network go with packets, so a lot overhead. It is ok to compress large files/data (and compression take CPU and memory bandwidth). Before to optimize, start to measure and understand where are the problems. Guesses are near always wrong (but if you have a lot (really a lot) of experience, but than you will fail often anyway).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Right i should have rephrased that. There is alot of overhead on https requests sure. But still when i have to store this data in a table i will end up on a terrific amount of bytes very quickly if i dont shave bytes.

Comment: In Python you have little control on the size of data (but if you are really on core python implementation). If you use Django, you need a database, and so you have little control on real data size (just use native formats for date, etc.). Such kind of optimization will become your nightmare, when you need to enhance the system.

Comment: IMHO this needs more info, especially regarding requirements, scope and the nature of the data (what is 2 ID bytes -- 16bit unsigned int?, "2 Variable A bytes" - 2 8bit unsigned ints?, what exactly is the 8 bytes of datetime, what granularity, and what range of timestamps do you care about?) | Regarding network, if the amount of data is less than the overhead of the protocol, I wouldn't worry about that (especially if it's a single record per request). The timestamps might offer the greatest possibility for savings. If you have blocks, you can take advantage of correlation between records.

Comment: For storage, it depends on what you really need to be able to do. This seems like some telemetry/monitoring. With not so many distinct IDs, I suspect there are many records for each ID.Timestamps are probably always increasing and with relatively small differences. I'd try to group the records into blocks, and compress and store those as binary blobs. Delta coding would help here. If A and B change seldom and/or slowly, delta coding may be useful too. Store the first timestamp, and ID, and then deltas of timestamp offsets, A and B. Entropy coding and some modelling...

Comment: Again, this depends on the requirements (and I guess you can't afford to just scale out to deal with the amount of data)... but perhaps an SQL database (or at least one storing such small records individually) is not the best storage solution for a system like this. But that's not to say PostgreSQL (I haven't experience with MySQL) is inflexible, for many years I've dealt with a DB for 1.4 billion accounts, tens of millions online at a time, where we had stored procedures that parsed and generated binary compressed blobs -- using functions implemented in C++ :) ).

Comment: Good calls all around Dan. Ill definitely take your advice!